# failed to export a model based deformable DETR

Tags: deployment, pytorch, export, trace, torchscript

## `when i try to export the deformable detr model into torchscript,it shows the error message!`

> Could not export Python function call 'MSDeformAttnFunction'. Remove calls to Python functions before export. Did you forget to add @script or @script_method annotation? If this is a nn.ModuleList, add it to constants:/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/layers/ms_deform_attn.py(165): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/layers/deformable_transformer.py(286): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/layers/deformable_transformer.py(413): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/layers/deformable_transformer.py(173): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/modeling/model/detection_transformer.py(200): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/autodl-tmp/project/deepsolo/adet/modeling/text_spotter_v1.py(222): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/export/flatten.py(259): <lambda>/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/export/flatten.py(294): forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(952): trace_module/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(735): tracedeploy/export_model00.py(126): export_tracingdeploy/export_model00.py(226): <module>

**anybody knows how to solve it?**
**i tried the method:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVazb.png)

**it exported successfully,but the exported model doesn't work!**

**and when i use this exported model to inference,it shows the error message:**

```
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1051: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/project/deploy/export_model.py", line 264, in <module>
    out1 = m(data)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
Traceback of TorchScript, serialized code (most recent call last):
  File "code/__torch__/detectron2/export/flatten.py", line 9, in forward
```

```
def forward(self: __torch__.detectron2.export.flatten.TracingAdapter,
    argument_1: Tensor) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]:
    _0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, = (self.model).forward(argument_1, )
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
    return (_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6)
  File "code/__torch__/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py", line 23, in forward
    batched_imgs = torch.unsqueeze_(_7, 0)
    x0 = torch.contiguous(batched_imgs)
    _8, _9, _10, _11, = (_0).forward(x0, image_size, )
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
    _12 = torch.softmax(_9, -1)
    prob = torch.sigmoid(torch.mean(_8, [-2]))
  File "code/__torch__/adet/modeling/model/detection_transformer.py", line 50, in forward
    _29 = getattr(self.input_proj, "1")
    _30 = getattr(self.input_proj, "0")
    _31 = (self.backbone).forward(x, image_size, )
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
    _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, = _31
    _58 = (_30).forward(_32, )
  File "code/__torch__/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py", line 104, in forward
    image_size: Tensor) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor]:
    _61 = getattr(self, "1")
    _62 = (getattr(self, "0")).forward(x, image_size, )
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
    _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, = _62
    pos_embed = torch.to((_61).forward(_63, ), 6)
  File "code/__torch__/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py", line 143, in forward
    _92 = torch.slice(torch.slice(_91, 0, 0, 125), 1, 0, 138)
    _93 = torch.view(CONSTANTS.c2, annotate(List[int], []))
    _94 = torch.copy_(_92, torch.expand(_93, [125, 138]))
          ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
    masks_per_feature_level0 = torch.ones([_85, _86, _87], dtype=11, layout=None, device=torch.device("cpu"), pin_memory=False)
    _95 = torch.select(masks_per_feature_level0, 0, 0)
Traceback of TorchScript, original code (most recent call last):
/root/autodl-tmp/project/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py(60): mask_out_padding
/root/autodl-tmp/project/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py(43): forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl
/root/autodl-tmp/project/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py(21): forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl
/root/autodl-tmp/project/adet/modeling/model/detection_transformer.py(168): forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl
/root/autodl-tmp/project/adet/modeling/text_spotter.py(220): forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/export/flatten.py(259): <lambda>
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/export/flatten.py(294): forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1039): _slow_forward
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1051): _call_impl
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(952): trace_module
/root/miniconda3/envs/deepsolo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(735): trace
/root/autodl-tmp/project/deploy/export_model.py(125): export_tracing
/root/autodl-tmp/project/deploy/export_model.py(224): <module>
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py(18): execfile
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py(1496): _exec
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py(1489): run
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py(2177): main
/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py(2195): <module>
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (50) must match the size of tensor b (125) at non-singleton dimension 0
```